# Structure Map method Populate() doesn't work for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, autofac, structuremap

According to [StructureMap documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/) and [examples](https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) from StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection repository it has to work but it doesn't.

Here is my Startup class:

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddTransient<IMovieRepository, MovieRepository>();

        var container = new Container();
        container.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.AddRegistry(new MyRegistry());
            config.Populate(services);
        });

        return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

And Registry:

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
    {
        public MyRegistry()
        {
            For<IMovieRepository>().Transient().Use<MovieRepository>();
        }
    }
```

And here is error screenshot:

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you add `using StructureMap;` to the top of the code file so you can call the [Populate exension method](https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/047864932fc27e27026176d7037481d76a1558ec/src/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ContainerExtensions.cs#L20)?

Comment: https://jeremydmiller.com/2018/01/29/sunsetting-structuremap/ With the sunsetting statement, probably you should consider moving to an alternative.

Comment: NightOwl888, of course I did add structure map name space, otherwise I wouldn't be able to create Container instance in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also add the following  nuget package to your project  in order to use the Populate method of the Configuration option.

The package name: StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

You do not have to import this library to the startup class though. "using StructureMap" there handles everything.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change IoC to Autofac. And the same problem appeared. I was following autofac documentation for asp.net core and skip a little detail. It took three days to figure out that I referenced to the wrong package. I referenced to the autofac package when what I was truly need was Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package. It's ridiculous mistake that kick me off for a three days. I am truly convinced that the same kind of mistake I did with structure map, so just look for StructureMap.AspNetCore package instead of StructureMap package and everything will work.

**!Read documentation extremely attentively!**